# How to get the list of common friends between any pair of friends in the network using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, key-value

I have three records like this
`[('a1', ['b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1']), ('a2', ['b1', 'c2', 'd2', 'e1']),('a3', ['b1', 'c2', 'd1', 'e2'])]`
containing the id for key as the list of the values for each key.

1. I want to get the total number of values in the list for each key in pyspark.
2. How I can get the list of the common friends between any pair of fiends in pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

1 Simply use the `size` function.

```
df = df.withColumn('num_friends', F.expr('size(friends)'))
```

2 Use the `array_intersect` function to get the intersection of arrays.

```
cp_df = df.toDF('key_pair', 'friends_pair')
cross_df = df.crossJoin(cp_df).filter('key!=key_pair')
cross_df = cross_df.select(F.create_map('key', 'key_pair').alias('key_pair'),
                           F.array_intersect('friends', 'friends_pair').alias('common_friends'))
cross_df.show(truncate=False)
```